# Error importing a python module in Django

Tags: python, django, elementtree, python-module

In my Django project, the following line throws an ImportError: "No module named elementtree".

```
  from elementtree import ElementTree
```

However, the module is installed (ie, I can run an interactive python shell, and type that exact line without any ImportError), and the directory containing the module is on the PYTHONPATH.  But when I access any page in a browser, it somehow can't find the module, and throws the ImportError.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Does Django use the same Python version as you are using in the shell?

Comment: Good question.  How do I find out which python django is using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you import `elementtree` within the django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Assuming you have multiple python versions and do not know which one is being used to run your  site, add the following to your view and push `python_ver` to your template, it will show you the Python version you are using:

```
import sys
python_ver = sys.version
```

You can also explicitly add the path to elementtree programatically in your `settings.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path to where elementtree resides')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Manually adding elementtree to the python path with `sys.path.append()` did the trick.

Comment: If you're just hacking this will probably work. If this is intended to be production code, your QA guys will not like you if you hack sys.path this way. Instead, you probably want to take a look at virtualenvs, which will let you have a specific version of django, elementtree and other python modules installed without a lot of opportunity for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've also run into cross-platform issues where ElementTree was available from different modules on different systems... this ended up working for me:

```
try:
    import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
except:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

May or may not help for you...

Answer (score 0):

Go into your installation directory

Example:

> C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages

And check if both elementtree and django are in there.

If they are both not there, then you probably have multiple installation directories for different versions of Python.

---

In any case, you can solve your problem by running this command:

> python setup.py install

Run it twice, once inside the download for django and once inside the download for elementtree.  It will install both of the downloads into whatever your current default python is.

References:

- [Installation documentation for ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm)
- [Installation documentation for Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-official-release)

Comment: elementtree is in my installation directory ($HOME/lib/python/), but I think I have multiple installation directories (all of which are on the PYTHONPATH, but I don't know if I need to do anything beyond that).  I'm also using a local python (`which python` gives me $HOME/local/bin/python, rather than the usual /usr/bin/python).

Comment: added some more details on how to possibly fix.