# Django: issues with importing custom Python3 class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django (so this is likely a Python3 question). Also, I have read the other similar questions such as [Error importing Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375382/error-importing-a-python-module-in-django).

I have a directory with the following structure:

> -- `my_class`
>
> -- -- `__init__.py`
>
> -- -- `custom_class_1.py`
>
> -- -- `custom_class_2.py`

where in the file **custom_class_2.py** there are the lines:

```
from custom_class_1 import Custom_Class_1 
class Custom_Class_2:
    self.thing = Custom_Class_1()
```

i.e. one class is built upon the others.

using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375382/error-importing-a-python-module-in-django) from the previously linked question

This causes the Django server to spit up this error:

```
from custom_class_1 import Custom_Class_1
ImportError: No module named 'Custom_Class_1'
```

which makes me think I did not follow pythonic conventions when defining a class, built on another class (but all in the same directory).

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does it work if you try `from .custom_class_1 import Custom_Class_1` (there's a dot in front of `custom_class_1` indicating a relative import).

Comment: That Django error message doesn't make sense -- it's saying `Custom_Class_1` is a _module_.  Are you sure that's the actual error message?

Comment: @MSeifert that seems to work!!

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, I am sure. That is what the terminal has in written whilst running the server and including `my_class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [relative import (see PEP 328 for more details)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

```
from .custom_class_1 import Custom_Class_1
```

The `.` in front of `custom_class_1` tells Python that the module `custom_class_1` should be imported from the same directory.

Comment: So this works from within the `views.py` file, but how would I do this in the `/template/my_app/index.html` file?

Comment: Could you ask a new question and include the relevant files there (feel free to link to the new question here in the comments)? I'm not sure I could answer this in a comment (without knowing your files).

Comment: Yup, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353505/django-import-custom-class-in-template-html-instead-of-view

Answer (score 0):

Imports in a Django project should use a module path from the project root.
For example, if `my_class` is at the root of your Django project,
then you can import `Custom_Class_2` with:

```
from my_class.custom_class_2 import Custom_Class_2
```

By the way, it's strange to name Python modules and classes with "class" in the name.