# Django: import custom class in template html instead of view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is an extension of my previous question [Django: issues with importing custom Python3 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352710/django-issues-with-importing-custom-python3-class/44352993?noredirect=1#comment75708611_44352993) in which I learned that in defining classes which are interdependent, to use a local reference (e.g. `from .my_other class ...`) as to prevent django from searching for a module of the same name.

Thus I now have my custom class imported in `views.py`. Since I am only using this class for one view, however, I would prefer to load it in `my_django_project/my_app/templates/my_app/view_with_my_class.html` rather than in `/my_django_project/my_app/views.py`

I tried:

```
{% from my_class import My_Custom_Class %}
```

but Django doesnt recognize the tag...

Comment: that's not a valid tag for a django template. What exactly are you trying to do inside a template with My_Custom_Class?

Comment: This question seems to indicate a misunderstanding of what templates are for. What would you do with that class even if you could import it?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov I know it is not a valid tag. I want to use a class for some process which generates some HTML output for the template of this site. Since this specifically affects one view, I rather somehow keep the code related to this with that view (or its template) but not necessarily all of the views...

Comment: @SumNeuron you do that in your view and pass it to the template as part of the context

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov thta is currently what I am doing in `views.py`, but the Django tutorials suggest doing as much in the template as possible...

Comment: @SumNeuron I don't think that is correct. Best practice I am aware of is fat model and thin view and template.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov ok, I will learn from that